# Is there a way to programatically add escape sequences to ncurses

Tags: ncurses

I am working on a ncursesw app that uses function keys.

Unfortunately it seems that there are some terminal emulators (notablly putty) that claim to be of terminal type "xterm" but send different escape sequences for the f1 to f4 keys from what a modern xterm sends (from some googling it seems that very old versions of xterm did the same).

ncursesw on my system just passes these escape sequences through to the app without interpreting them.

I would like to make my program accept these additional escape sequences for function keys. Is there a way to programatically add escape sequences to ncurses or will I need to write my own escape sequence interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, using the call "define_key" ( http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/define_key.3x.html )

The documentation is not clear on whether it allows more than one escape sequence for a given "key" or not. My testing shows that it does allow it. So one can simply define the additional sequences.

```
define_key("\e[11~",KEY_F1);
define_key("\e[12~",KEY_F2);
define_key("\e[13~",KEY_F3);
define_key("\e[14~",KEY_F4);
```

You may want to surround this with a termname check so it only applies when the claimed terminal type is xterm (I did in my actual program but my actual program was written in pascal).